# What is the reason for the list comprehension of list as input of the any function?

Tags: python, tuples, any

I was reading codes from an opensource program.

And I encounter this code:

```
drets = []

...... omitted code to insert some values into drets

d0ret = any((dret for dret in drets))
```

The list, drets is iterable by itself so it can be passed into the 'any' directly.
Why does the code convert it into tuple? I don't get the point at all.

Comment: That's not a tuple, that's a generator expression. And yes, it's superfluous.

Comment: There is no point. This looks like someone doesn't really understand what they are doing when they copied the approach from somewhere else.